# Postgres: how do I filter by a datetime field with infinity and -infinity?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a select query with filter a datetime field that equals to 'infinity' and '-infinity':

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dt = <??? infitity ???> OR dt = <??? -infinity ???>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE dt = 'infinity'
   OR dt = '-infinity';
```

This assumes that `dt` is a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` column.

You can also be explicit about this (to make it obvious that it isn't a typo):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE dt = 'infinity'::timestamp
   OR dt = '-infinity'::timestamp;
```

Comment: Explain to me, please. What does `::timestamp` mean in the syntax? I'm new in postgres.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: it's an explicit cast to a `timestamp` value: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: Beat me in seconds :) However, note that the binding of infinity values (f.ex. in prepared statements) can be tricky, because a lot of platform do not support such extreme values in their implementation of datetime/timestamp construct.

Comment: @pozs: it is possible through JDBC

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name with String + explicit cast, or with String + unspecified stringtype, yes. But not with the dedicated temporal setters AFAIK

Comment: @pozs: The JDBC driver maps the infinity literals to values of `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`, .e.g `'+infinity'` can be passed as `new java.sql.Date(9223372036825200000l)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see; then this is a PostgreSQL driver specific thing I assume. And a little odd IMHO, but still better than throwing exceptions when retrieving such values.